# ask about the meaning of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script `application.sh`, as follows.

```
#! /bin/busybox sh

set -o nounset -o errexit

readonly emul_script="/usr/local/bin/emul.sh" 
readonly profile="/etc/vendor/profile"    
source "${profile}"                

_usage() {
        cat << EOF
${0} [-d]
        -d      :debug
EOF
```

The above script starts a specific application. My question is related to the part starting from `_usage`, I do not quite understand what it means and cannot see how it is used.

Answer (score 4):

The `<<` is the [heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) construct and `cat`s everything up to the end marker (`EOF` in this case) to stdout.

The `${0}` is the name of the input file and this will print something like the following to stdout:

```
application.sh [-d]
    -d      :debug
```

You are missing the trailing `}` by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what trojanfoe says, `_usage()` is a shell function.

But it is never called, nor is the application itself called, so I suppse that is only part of a script.

Answer (score 0):

The `_usage` function might be called from `${profile}` script that is sourced just above it.

Beware, that you may want to put it before the `source` line, because, strictly speaking, it has to be defined before it is used.